# Invalid use of group by function when count within sum

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, mariadb

I have the next query:

```
select H.UserID, N.LocatieID, N.Norm * COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(H.Starttijd)) AS 
Norm FROM Locatienorm N LEFT JOIN Uur H ON N.LocatieID = H.LocatieID GROUP BY 
H.UserID, N.LocatieID, N.Norm
```

It gives me the next result

[image]

I would like to have the result:

6 1 0.56

6 4 0.96

But when I Sum the norm I get the error:

> invalid use of group by function

.

So like this:

```
select H.UserID, 
       N.LocatieID, 
       SUM(N.Norm * COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(H.Starttijd))) AS 
Norm 
FROM Locatienorm N 
LEFT JOIN Uur H ON N.LocatieID = H.LocatieID 
GROUP BY 
H.UserID, N.LocatieID, N.Norm
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not supported?

Server version: 10.1.31 MariaDB Server

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest the group functions. Try this rather -

```
SELECT H.UserID
      ,N.LocatieID
      ,SUM(Norm)
FROM ( SELECT H.UserID
             ,N.LocatieID
             ,N.Norm * COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(H.Starttijd)) AS Norm 
       FROM Locatienorm N
       LEFT JOIN Uur H ON N.LocatieID = H.LocatieID
       GROUP BY H.UserID, N.LocatieID) A
GROUP BY H.UserID
        ,N.LocatieID
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting aggregation function like that won't work.  But you can aggregate in a sub-query and then aggregate on the result in the outer query.

Example:

```
SELECT H.UserID, N.LocatieID, 
SUM(N.Norm * H.TotalDays) AS Norm 
FROM Locatienorm AS N
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
    LocatieID, UserID, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(Starttijd)) AS TotalDays 
   FROM Uur
   GROUP BY LocatieID, UserID
) AS H ON N.LocatieID = H.LocatieID
GROUP BY N.LocatieID, H.UserID
```

You can test it on rextester [here](http://rextester.com/TPYHP80223)